# Precompiled header with XeLaTeX not working

Tags: xetex, header-footer, miktex

I have been using precompiled headers to speed up my compilation times (both in `pdfLaTeX` and `XeLaTeX`) for some time. For `XeLaTeX`, in order to use the `fontspec` package, I have always used `etoolbox` package `\AtEndPreamble{...}` command, and have not had any problems.

However, since a couple of weeks, `XeLaTeX` precompiled headers are not working for me. A MWE *Test.tex* file like:

```
\documentclass{article}
```

When I use:

```
xelatex -ini -shell-escape -job-name="Test" "&xelatex "Test".tex\dump"
```

Leads me to this error:

```
! Can't \dump a format with native fonts or font-mappings.
```

However, when I try `pdfLaTeX` instead (i.e., `pdflatex -ini -shell-escape -job-name="Test" "&pdflatex "Test".tex\dump"`), works like a charm.

Any idea? I'm using MikTeX x64 with latest updated packages available (no *pre-release* packages), and TeXstudio in Windows 8.1. I have also tried reinstalling and updating MikTeX, but the error keeps happening.

Thanks!

Comment: This s due to the fact that xelatex now defaults to TU (Unicode) encoding. Let me have a think if there is any easy option....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your template file to reset the encoding to the old 7-bit default

```
\RequirePackage[OT1]{fontenc}
\documentclass{article}
```

then you can dump the format.

You will need (as before) to select a Unicode encoding in your document, to enable proper typesetting.

Incidentally your comandline looks a bit weird, I wasn't sure of the quoting conventions in force or why `\dump` appears twice. in bash i used the following to test:

```
xelatex -ini  \&xelatex testfile \\dump
```

where I got the error that you showed unless `testfile.tex` setto OT1 first, as shown above.

Comment: It was that. Thank you very much! I also edit my post: there was a typo, as I don't need `.text\dump` twice. Also, the quoting are because my user commands in TeXstudio: my user command is set to `xelatex -ini -shell-escape -job-name="%" "&xelatex %.tex\dump"`, in order to include posible spaces in filenames.